# How can I write a function that will create a subset of my data frame based on the values in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have constructed a data frame consisting of bookings in dollars by day for a two-year period. In the data frame, the index is the date of the booking, and there is another column that is the quarter of the booking (ex. Q2-2018). I've also set up a cumulative sum by quarter so that I can query any date and see total bookings for that quarter at that point in time.

My end goal is to get an average curve of the cumulative bookings by quarter, but I am having issues early on understanding how to subset my data frame into quarters so that I can apply a curve function to each subset. I want to avoid subsetting by explicitly listing the quarter values because they will be different in a future dataset.

```py
newbusiness_raw = csv.reader('newbusinesstrend_raw')

nb_raw = pandas.read_csv(
                         'newbusinesstrend_raw.csv',
                         index_col="Close Date",
                         parse_dates=True)

nb_cum = nb_raw.dropna(subset=['Amount'])
nb_cum = nb_cum.sort_index()
nb_cum['CumAmount'] = nb_cum.groupby('FQ')['Amount'].cumsum()
```